# st terminal: Clone exactly colors of console to terminal

Tags: terminal, console, suckless-terminal

I have serious problemm when trying to have same view - exactly same colors of console then port them to terminal.

Console uses `linux` or `screen` that supports only `8` colors, the problem is terminal has different definition of those `8` color and has displayed different from console.

For example the same color code of `1` look different on console and terminal.

I need a way to fix this and make it feel like I haven't switch from terminal and console at all.

If possible apply to st-terminal.

EDIT:

st has this color codes, how to make it look like same as terminal?

```
static const char *colorname[] = {
> /* 8 normal colors */
> "black",
> "red3",
> "green3",
> "yellow3",
> "blue2",
> "magenta3",
> "cyan3",
> "gray90",

> /* 8 bright colors */
> "gray50",
> "red",
> "green",
> "yellow",
> "#5c5cff",
> "magenta",
> "cyan",
> "white",

> [255] = 0,

> /* more colors can be added after 255 to use with DefaultXX */
> "#cccccc",
> "#555555",

 };

unsigned int defaultfg = 7;
unsigned int defaultbg = 0;
static unsigned int defaultcs = 256;
static unsigned int defaultrcs = 257;
```

Comment: gnome-terminal doesn't use those colors, because it doesn't use rgb.txt at all.  Rather, it defaults to imitating xterm's rgb values, but  may be overridden to use "other" colors.  Since there's no documentation, you'll only get poor answers.

Comment: That's what I'm guessing, from what I see I can pretty sure there's different between them with the same color code. So the question should be what `#XXXXXX` should fallback exactly to `8` console colors as in st's `colorname` array.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux console controls see `man console_codes`. Entry on colours:

> ```
>    ESC ]     OSC      (Should be: Operating  system  command)  ESC  ]  P
>                       nrrggbb:  set  palette,  with parameter given in 7
>                       hexadecimal digits after the final P :-(.  Here  n
>                       is  the  color  (0–15),  and  rrggbb indicates the
>                       red/green/blue values (0–255).   ESC  ]  R:  reset
>                       palette
> ```

For instance,

```
echo -e "\033]P7ffffff"
```

sets colour 7 to "bright white".

Comment: I've just update `#1`, I tried to do some `gray00`, that mean even `gray00` to lowest color of `gray` terminal always look brighter than console. I couldn't set color gray darker. So possible I have to use `#XXXXXX` format to set color possible close to console, but what `#XXXXXX` to use?